# how to fixed same size bootstrap card when window width is continuously decrease?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating two bootstrap card in the same row.two cards have different text element.but when I decrease the window size one of two cards change its height according to the inner text element. I want to fixed two cards height either window size is small or not..how to do this? can any one help me? Thanks in advance.... :)

```css
#edu
{ padding: 30px 20px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <!--jQuery library--> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="edu">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card" id="cardid" >
 <div class="card-header"><center>Education</center></div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">● hello hello hello hello hello 2019</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><br>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
<h5 class="card-title"> ●hello hello hello hello helooo</h5>
        <p class="card-text">something...................................................</p>
<h5 class="card-title"> ● hello hello hello hello hello</h5>
        <p class="card-text">sometthing here........................</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
 <div class="card-header"><center>Traings & Online Courses</center> </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">TRAINING</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● .........................................................<br> ● ..............................................</p>
 <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● blah blah blah blah..... <br>
●blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
<h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
        
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First you should understand how it works the BOOTSTRAP grid system for different screen sizes. Hope you're expecting to have same width for both cards when you're resizing. Use BOOTSTRAP grid classes to adjust your cards. Ex: class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"

Comment: @Harshana okay, i tried this , but cards are same width only when window have that specific size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, It's working for me.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--jQuery library--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .card-body {
   padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .card-content {
   padding: 1.25rem;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row my-4">
     <div class="col">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm d-flex">
               <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                  <div class="card-header"><center>Education</center></div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                 <h5 class="card-title">● hello hello hello hello hello 2019</h5>
              <p class="card-text"><br>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <h5 class="card-title"> ●hello hello hello hello helooo</h5>
              <p class="card-text">something...................................................</p>
        <h5 class="card-title"> ● hello hello hello hello hello</h5>
              <p class="card-text">sometthing here........................</p>
          </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           <div class="col-sm d-flex">
               <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header"><center>Traings & Online Courses</center></div>
             <div class="card-content">
              <h5 class="card-title">TRAINING</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● .........................................................<br> ● ..............................................</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● blah blah blah blah..... <br>
        ●blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
       </div>
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @Makdia Hussain its working..but in why in bootstrap 3 its not working?